# Statements inside ?: expression

Tags: java, scala

I'm learning scala and trying to understand the following sentence:

> In Java you can't put statements inside a ?: expression

Can someone explain this to me, perhaps with an example and maybe in the context of Scala?

Comment: AFAIK, Scala doesn't have such an construct `boolexpr ? expr1 : expr2`. However you can use if-else expression to achieve the same effect because if-else has has a return value.

Answer (score 6):

Java has a ternary conditional operator inherited from C, it looks like this:

```
int x = some_condition ? 1 : 2;
```

`x` will be equal to `1` if `some_condition` is true, and to `2` otherwise. Java requires that arguments to this operator are expressions, i.e. things which result in concrete values. For example, method call or constant literal are expressions, but a loop or a conditional statement or a variable definition are not expressions because they do not have meaningful value. This means that you cannot return, say, variable definition from a function, but you can return result of method call.

Scala does not have ternary operator. But it does not need one because in Scala *everything* is expression. Even loops - they result in a special value of `Unit` type. Conditionals are also expressions, they return a value of common supertype of all branches. Because of this you can use plain conditional "statement" instead of ternary operator. This Scala snippet is equivalent to Java one above:

```scala
val x = if (some_condition) 1 else 2
```

Moreover, in Scala every *block* is an expression too (its value is the value of the last line in the block), so you can have statements, for example assignments, inside the "ternary operator":

```scala
val x = if (some_condition) {
    val y = some_computation()
    y*2
} else {
    val z = another_computation()
    z + 3
}
```

Answer (score 3):

More generally, you can't put arbitrary statements in any expression, not just the conditional expression.

A method's block is a list of statements. A statement is made up of other statements and/or expressions. But expressions, being the building blocks of statements, do normally not contain statements.

Well, there is one exception: a class creation expression of the form

```
new C(argument list) { class definition }
```

This creates at compile time a new class that is a subclass of `C` and at runtime an instance of that class. Hence it would be possible to write something like:

```
cond ? (new Object() { 
         public int get() { System.out.println("Hi"); return 42; }
       }).get() 
     : 0
```

to smuggle a statement into an expression.

Comment: Does that compile? Because `new Object().get()` should tell you that there is no such method (even though you define one in an anonymous subclass).

Comment: @zapl Nope, as long as you don't assign the reference to a variable of type Object, it's fine.

Comment: Oh you're right, I was under the impression that the compile time type of such construct would still be `Object` which would not allow calling `get`.

Comment: Very clever! It's interesting if it is possible to make it even cleaner with Java 8 lamdas...

Answer (score 1):

The thing you put inside the ?: expression are other expressions.  The first one must evaluate to a boolean, and the second and third evaluate to the same type (int, String, etc.).  A statement is something that is executed, an expression is something that results in a value.  It gets confusing because you can put executable stuff inside an expression.